# how to log user input

Tags: linux, logging, tcsh

we have a lot of users `su`ing the same account and i want to track what commands each of them runs without the outputs of those commands.

i tried piping su to `tee` which worked great, except it also gives me the output.
`script` did the same thing. another solution i have tried was using strace, but that both gives me keystrokes which could capture passwords AND doesnt tell me what happens in subshells or at least i couldnt figure out how to use it properly. i've also tried all sorts of interesting redirections, but all of the proposed solutions were for bash while im stuck with tcsh...
i dont want to use a keylogger because i dont want to accidentally capture a password, i realize this means that i wont know what people do once they launch text editors, but i can live with that.

the perfect solution would be to capture the "echo", that is the stuff the user "sends" to the shell when he hits return, but i did not manage to formulate a good enough question for google to be helpful on that front.
could any one point me in the right direction?

*take into account that i do not have root privilages

edit:
unfortunately, our version of sudo is < 1.7.4p4

Comment: This is a job for [**`sudo`**](https://www.sudo.ws/). I recommend you have your administrator put everyone who needs privileged access into a group, configure sudo with the appropriate command aliases, and change any passwords on the system that have been shared. Passwords are like bubblegum. They should be kept to yourself, and cause a sticky mess when shared.

Comment: @ghoti we actually ` sudo su` the account. i understand that /var/log/secure is supposed to hold what im looking for, but with no access to root this doesnt help me :\

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su` isn't much better than `su` alone, but you might want to have a look at the I/O logging abilities activated via the `LOG_INPUT` and `LOG_OUTPUT` tags in the `sudoers(5)` man page.

> `log_input`
>
>   If set,
>   `sudo`
>   will run the command in a pseudo tty
>     and log all user input.  If the standard input is not connected
>     to the user's tty, due to I/O redirection or because the command
>     is part of a pipeline, that input is also captured
>     and stored in a separate log file.
>
> Input is logged to the directory specified by the `iolog_dir` option
>   (`/var/log/sudo-io` by default) using a unique session ID
>   that is included in the normal sudo log line, prefixed with `TSID=`.
>   The `iolog_file` option may be used to
>   control the format of the session ID.
>
> Note that user input may contain sensitive information such as passwords
>   (even if they are not echoed to the screen), which will be stored in the log file unencrypted. In most cases, logging the command output via log_output is all that is required.
>
> `log_output`
>
>   If set,
>   `sudo`
>   will run the command in a pseudo tty and log all output that is sent to the screen, similar to the script(1) command.
>     If the standard output or standard error is not connected to the user's tty, due to I/O redirection or because the command is part of a pipeline, that output is also captured and stored in separate log files.
>
> Output is logged to the directory specified by the `iolog_dir` option
>   (`/var/log/sudo-io` by default) using a unique session ID
>   that is included in the normal sudo log line, prefixed with `TSID=`.
>   The `iolog_file` option may be used to
>   control the format of the session ID.
>
> Output logs may be viewed with the sudoreplay(8) utility,
>   which can also be used to list or search the available logs.

Use `visudo` to modify your `sudoers files. You'll need to add these two tags to any sudo entries that provide permissions to groups. For example:

```
%admins         ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: LOG_INPUT: LOG_OUTPUT: ALL
```

You'll also need to set the logging location with the `iolog_dir` option. For example:

```
Defaults iolog_dir=/var/log/sudo-io/%{user}
```

Note that this requires sudo version 1.7.4p4 at minimum.

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention this. i wanted to try his solution but we have an older version of sudo

Comment: Time to upgrade sudo.

Comment: static project environment, unfortunately :\   quite a pickle

Comment: Indeed. Well, I answered your question as asked which didn't mention sudo or its version. With your revision you've invalidated my answer for your purposes, but I'll leave it in case someone else comes across this and wants to do something similar with a more recent version of sudo.